# Rails redirect_to @service is redirecting to localhost in non-dev enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

In my UAT enviroment I'm creating a new Service, after the evaluation of .save the expected result is that I should be redirected to /service/x

```
 if @servicio.save
      flash[:success] = "Servicio creado correctamente"
      redirect_to @servicio
    else
```

But I'm beign redirected to https://localhost/service/x

[image]

I'm using heroku, The logs show the following:

```
2020-04-25T17:37:43.904693+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-04-25T17:37:43.904611 #4] DEBUG -- : [7d39fb4a-ec38-4814-b0aa-83fc6c98bea6]   Servicio Create (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "servicios" ("codigo", "estado", "titulo", "descripcion", "inicio", "fin", "planta_id", "empresa_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["codigo", "S2"], ["estado", "A"], ["titulo", "S2"], ["descripcion", "S2"], ["inicio", "2020-04-25"], ["fin", "2020-04-25"], ["planta_id", 5], ["empresa_id", 1], ["created_at", "2020-04-25 17:37:43.902401"], ["updated_at", "2020-04-25 17:37:43.902401"]]
2020-04-25T17:37:43.907186+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-04-25T17:37:43.907096 #4] DEBUG -- : [7d39fb4a-ec38-4814-b0aa-83fc6c98bea6]    (2.2ms)  COMMIT
2020-04-25T17:37:43.907765+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-25T17:37:43.907704 #4]  INFO -- : [7d39fb4a-ec38-4814-b0aa-83fc6c98bea6] Redirected to https://localhost/servicios/16
2020-04-25T17:37:43.907909+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-25T17:37:43.907864 #4]  INFO -- : [7d39fb4a-ec38-4814-b0aa-83fc6c98bea6] Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
```

I've been checking config_var at heroku and comparing those between my UAT enviroment and my PROD enviroment, no clue yet!

Comment: It is very odd but request.base_url returns the correct `https: //mydomain.com` . So no idea why redirect_to isnt working

Answer (score 1):

Solved, after a couple of days looking in history it seems that the following block was in the application controller:

```
 def default_url_options
    { host: ENV["DOMAIN"] || "localhost:3000" }
  end
```

Removed it and works as expected.